# No search results in document library when "Hide physical url from search"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-search

In our solution we are using friendly url's. For this reason we have set "Hide physical url from search" on all pages. But with this option set to TRUE no pages are returned in library search. If I turn the option off the page turns up in search. Is there a configuration on the list etc. that makes pages turn up in the list search. FYI the pages turn up in my standard search page.